# Power went out during install 15.10 Server

Tags: server

I got through the configuration and LVM. I chose the OpenSSH and my power went out during it. I know turn it back on and follow through and its stuck on 39% during the starting up the partition part.

I don't know what to do

Comment: Try wiping out and reformatting your partition, then reinstall.

Comment: how do I do that? Have steps for me? New to this

Comment: It's a little complicated since the Ubuntu Server media is installation only (no live mode), so you could get a GNU/Linux live media and do the work from there. If you have a display and can run a GUI you can do it very easily with GParted, but if it is CLI only then you can do it with parted/fdisk/cfdisk (parted is the easiest).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest, not necessarily the quickest way  is to sinply start over with a fresh install.  Also,  reformat the hard drive, a quuck format will do,  this will help problems from occurring later.

BUT FIRST,  BEFORE DOING ANYTHING at all, get a good USP and connect both the monitor and the server  itself to it.  This way you can gracefully shut down the server when another power outsge occurs.

Comment: My USP just arrived right now. I will do that. How can I simply start over? It is an install disc and new server out of the box.